# An awkard alignment in the comments 

Tags: bug, design, comments

I am attaching below a picture to indicate how the arrows intended to indicate you have upvoted some commment is aligned awkardly. Is that by-design or something that should go unnoticed? Anyway, it is not aesthetically pleasing.

[image]

Comment: You mean that they have some positive depth? Honestly, I kinda like it `:)`

Comment: @tohecz The second comment that has been only once upvoted (in the image) is little outside the perpendicular bisector of the base of the triangle indicating that the first comment has upvoted twelve times. :)

Comment: So you have issue with horizontal alignment? I like it that way too, because the triangle belongs to the number IMHO and then it's best placed just after the number, no matter how many digits are there.